# Putting all the output in a specific textbox in a while loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, textbox, while-loop, output

So all I want here to happen is that how can I put all the given output in the answer textbox.

UPDATE

```
<html>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction() {
          var x = parseInt(document.f1.n1.value);
          var y = parseInt(document.f1.n2.value);
          if(x>=y) {
              document.write("Invalid");
          }
          while (x<y)
          {
              document.write(x)
              x=x+1;
          }
      }
  </script>
  <form name=f1 onsubmit="return false">
   First no. <input type="text" name="n1">
   Second no. <input type="text" name="n2">
   Answer: <input type="text" name="ans" disabled>
   <input type="submit" onClick="myFunction()">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What given output are you trying to put in the answer input?

Comment: Your form tag isn't even closed nor do you have an 'answer textbox'.

Comment: @brso05 the answer of the document.write(x) because when I try it in I.E. it will only show the output numbers , nothing else. All I want to do here is that put the output numbers in the answer textbox. Its like i put 2 in the first no and 5 in the second no. The answer will be 3 and 4. How can I put 3 and 4 in the answer textbox.

Comment: @JohnVernonL.Manacup look at my answer it shows you how.

Comment: @brso05 it still only show the answers in a new page and not in the answer textbox

Comment: @brso05 I want the values of x in the while loop to be seen in the answer textbox. Not the x and y.

Comment: `while (x > y) { x = x + 1; }` - infinite loop

Comment: @JohnVernonL.Manacup I just updated my answer I think it might be close to what you want just copy and paste the full code I gave you it should atleast give you a starting point.

Comment: @JohnVernonL.Manacup please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: @brso05 I'm just very new about this Javascript. How can I put my if condition if both numbers are equal and in the answer it will say invalid? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you very much. This is just what I needed. Can you help me with finding a javascript code by when I insert a number and hit a submit button it will have the exponent of that number. Its like 4 to the fourth power.

Comment: @JohnVernonL.Manacup I just updated the code to include `x >= y`.

Comment: @JohnVernonL.Manacup I'm not sure exactly what you mean can you provide a specific example of inputs and expected output?

Comment: @brso05 check it out.

Comment: @brso05 just update it. Try it out.

Comment: @JohnVernonL.Manacup I posted another update to my answer if this helps you please mark my answer as correct thanks!

Comment: @brso05 can you revise the exponential. The base number is not necessary needed. Can you like make the exponent be fixed in a way that when I put a number, it is the same number as your exponent like 2^2 3^3 4^4

Comment: @JohnVernonL.Manacup There you go updated...

Comment: You sure know alot! Thank you very much.

Comment: @brso05 bro quick favor, can you do me a script wherein i have a base number and a number and when I submit it, it will generate the sequence of like example 2 is the base number and the exponent is 5 it will generate 2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5 ?

Comment: @Codex just added another update for the above code.  It starts at 0 however instead of 1 example 2^0 + 2^1 + etc... you can change to start at 1 if you want just change the for loop from staring at 0 to starting at 1.

Comment: Got it. It's very useful for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Give answer input an id:

```
<input id="answerTextBox" type="text" name="ans" disabled>
```

After while loop populate answer textbox:

```
while (x>y)
{
document.getElementById("answerTextBox").value += ("" + x);
x=x+1;
}
```

This will put x and y in your answer textbox.

UPDATE******

```
<html>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction() {
          document.getElementById("answerTextBox").value = "";
          var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
          var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);
          if(x >= y)
          {
              document.getElementById("answerTextBox").value = "Invalid Input";
          }
          while (x < y)
          {
              document.getElementById("answerTextBox").value += ("" + x);
              x=x+1;
          }
      }
  </script>
   First no. <input type="text" name="n1" id="n1">
   Second no. <input type="text" name="n2" id="n2">
   Answer: <input id="answerTextBox" type="text" name="ans" readonly>
   <input type="button" onClick="myFunction()">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE for exponential************************

```
<html>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction() {
          document.getElementById("answerTextBox").value = "";
          var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
          var y = x;
          var answer = 1;
          for(var i = 0; i < y; i++)
          {
              answer = answer * x;
          }
          document.getElementById("answerTextBox").value = answer;
      }
  </script>
   Enter Number: <input type="text" name="n1" id="n1">
   Answer: <input id="answerTextBox" type="text" name="ans" readonly>
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="myFunction()">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE Add Exponents*****************

```
<html>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction() {
          document.getElementById("answerTextBox").value = "";
          var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
          var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);
          var answer = 0;
          for(var i = 0; i <= y; i++)
          {
              answer = answer + Math.pow(x, i);
          }
          document.getElementById("answerTextBox").value = answer;
      }
  </script>
   Enter Base Number: <input type="text" name="n1" id="n1">
   Enter Highest Exponent: <input type="text" name="n2" id="n2">
   Answer: <input id="answerTextBox" type="text" name="ans" readonly>
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="myFunction()">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
The number inserted in the textbox is the number of exponent it will generate. The sample is 3. 3X3X3 is 27. <br>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
var x = document.f1.n1.value;
while(x<27)
{
x=x*3;
}
document.write(x)
}
</script>
<form name="f1" onsubmit="return false">
First no. <input type="text"name="n1" value=3 disabled>
<input type="submit" onClick="myFunction()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Update: The Exponent in any number.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are trying to accomplish...sorry